# how to make autosum (calculation) in javascript with features add/remove form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with calculation in javascript. the problem is when I create add / remove in modal (i'am using uikit css). I can't make the autosum when add new form. Only on the first form that works but the second form doesn't work.

Here I include the sorce code.

```
<form id="old" name='autoSumForm'>
  <b>aa</b>
  <input type='text' name='aa' style="text-align:right;"  size='23'   onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" />
  <b>bb</b>
  <input type='text' name='bb'  style="text-align:right;"  size='23'   onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" />
  <b>cc</b>
  <input readonly type=text value='0' name="cc"  readonly>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Clone" id="clone" />

<script>
  function startCalc(){
  interval = setInterval("calc()",1);}
  function calc(){
  one = document.autoSumForm.aa.value;
  two = document.autoSumForm.bb.value;

  document.autoSumForm.cc.value = (one * two)}
  function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);}
</script>

<script>
$( 'input#clone' ).click(
    function()
    {
       $( 'form#old textarea' ).text( $( 'form#old textarea' ).val() )
      $("form#old").clone().attr( 'id', 'new_form' ).appendTo("body")     
    }
)
</script>
```

And this issue:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LSps.png)

I hope somebody wants to help me with this problem, I've searched for another way but the result is nothing works. please help me, thankyou..

Comment: I'd remove the "working" code - it just clutters up your question and makes for more work for people trying to answer.

Comment: Further @Venantius comment, if you do want that people will help you, please create a **working** [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so we could actually **see** the problem and will try to debug it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code ain't working because there is only one `document.autoSumForm` initially. When you clone it, `document.autoSumForm` returns 2 `autoSumForm`.

At this line `document.autoSumForm.aa.value`, this would give `aa` as undefined.

You'll have to access the form individually to work for the specific form.